# My required attribute is not working in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called TextInput, code is below:

```
const TextInput = ({ placeholder, width, required }) => {
  if (!width) {
    width = 100
  }
  return (
    <input
      className={input}
      style={{ width: width + '%' }}
      type="text"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      required={required}
    />
  )
}

export default TextInput
```

I implemented in the example below:

```
const LoginForm = () => {
return(
  <form className={styles.form}>
    <TextInput placeholder="First name" width={100} required="required"/>
    {'\n'}
    <TextInput placeholder="Last name" width={100} />
    <TextInput placeholder="Gender" width={100} />
    <TextInput placeholder="Date of Birth" width={100} />

    <Button type='Submit' href="/ohip-survey" style={
      {
        backgroundColor: "#a7d1a7",
        color: "black",
        fontSize: "large",
        width: "7em",
        fontWeight: "500",
        maxHeight: "30px",
        borderRadius:"10px",
        float: "right"
      }
    }>Submit</Button>
  </form>
)

}

export default LoginForm
```

However, the required field is not working, when clicking submit button with no input value, the form can still be submitted and redirect me to the href page. I'm a beginner of this, does anybody know why?